# How should I cache semi-static database query results?

Tags: .net, database, caching

**Situation:**

The program I'm working on uses a very large SQLite database as data backend (this cannot be changed and is not relevant to the question). Indexes were applied in a reasonable manner and all queries complete very quickly, but the amount of requests is also very large.

I identified a primary bottleneck with a particular kind of query which will read a bunch of rows that are semi-static: any previous results will be valid, but additional rows might be returned. The number of possible query-result pairs is within "a few GB" when stored as C# data structure.

The solution I'm thinking of would bundle this query type in a cache class. It would store all results for a particular query in a Dictionary-like structure. Known queries will update only the possibly added subset of results for this query. So far no problem.

**Proposed solution:**

Since the cache may exceed the available RAM, it is required to allow C# to GC some of the cached results. Reasonably, the least used results should be purged first. For this purpose, the only solution I'm only aware are WeakReferences.

I would thus have all results that are of supposedly low value be stored only weakly. I would then implement a continuous self-check on access (or alternatively a background thread) which checks for removed values and, if many are found, more aggressively converts strong to weak references to allow the GC to claim more.

This process would leave those results which are deemed more valuable as strong refs unless the pressure gets very high.

**Question:**

Do I need to implement this myself, or is there a built-in solution that accomplishes this or a similar task? And more generally: Is the above proposal a reasonable solution at all?

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft web site
Avoid using weak references as an automatic solution to memory management problems.

Need to define "available RAM".
.NET has an object size limit and a Dictionary is an object.
The limit is like 1 GB and with X64 I think you can go higher.
And it is not a hard limit - it is contiguous memory.

If you want to delete less used rows it will had a lot of overhead
Purging old will most likely be O(n)

I would just go after the 1st GB and see what that get you.
You can also add a second (and third) dictionary as they are separate objects.
But at a certain point you are going to have trouble getting contiguous memory.

I think a better approach would be to have the database track the most used.
Then right when your app starts download the most used 1 GB.